# How can I fetch data from an API, process the data and render everything after the data was parsed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, onload

My problem is that while fetching data from an API the website is already loaded, so for a second or so I see the default data in the elements and only after that the element data is updated.

I've already tried many ways like `Async/Await` and `Promises` and also events like `jQuery.ready()`, `window.onload()`, and the `DOMContainerLoaded` event on the fetch method but everytime, the page loads first.

In short, I want to (in order):

- Get the data from an API (json)
- Parse the data to an Object
- Updated the elements on the page with the data
- Render the whole page

#### This is what I have at the moment:

### Player.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/classes.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/player.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img id="playerAvatar" class="avatar" alt="The avatar of the player">
      <h2 id="nick"></h2>
      <!-- More Stuff Later -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### player.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function(){
  const player = await processPlayerData();
  fillPlayerData(player);
});

async function processPlayerData(){
  const user = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('id');
  const json = await requestData('/api/player/'+ user, {method: "GET"});
  let player = new Player();

  if("errors" in json)
    player = null;
  else
    player.fillData(json);

  return player;
}

async function requestData(dir, options) {
  const response = await fetch(dir, options)
    .then((response) => { return response.json(); });
    return response;
}

function fillPlayerData(player){
  if(player === null)
    alert("The user does not exist!");
  else{
    document.getElementById('nick').innerHTML = "AlexMFV"; //player.nickname;
    document.getElementById('playerAvatar').src = "https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/colorful-powder-explosion-in-all-directions-in-a-nice-composition-picture-id890147976?s=612x612"; //player.avatarUrl;
    //Fill the elements with all the player data
    //Get all player matches
  }

  return true;
}
```

#### And also on the server I have a method that is gathering the JSON from the API:

```
async function getPlayerData(req, res){
  let value;
  try{
    const user = req.params.id;
    value = await fetch(strPlayerData.replace('<usr>', user), packet).then((res) => { return res.json(); });
    res.json(value);
  }
  catch(e){
    error(res, e);
  }
}
```

If there is something that you don't understand please tell me so that I can provide more information.

Edit: If you want to try it so that you can see what I mean, the project is available here: https://faceitstats.alexmfv.com/player.html?id=Alex

Comment: Keep a `loading` state variable, and if loading display some sort of loading icon, then render the page after the data is loaded.

Comment: yes, the page loads first - it has to load, otherwise your `document.getElementById` calls will fail

Comment: one thing you could do is `<div class="container" style="display:none">` and then once you've fetched the data, remove the display:none form that element - because the way you've coded this, you rely on those elements with id `nick` and `playerAvatar` to exist otherwise your code will fail

Comment: Yes but supposedly you can load the DOM first and manipulate the elements and render the page afterwards, but I’ll try to add the elements dynamically to see if it mitigates this problem.